# mv Bash Shell Command (on Mac) overwriting files even with a -i?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am flattening a directory of nested folders/picture files down to a single folder.  I want to move all of the nested files up to the root level.

There are 3,381 files (no directories included in the count).  I calculate this number using these two commands and subtracting the directory count (the second command):

```
find ./ | wc -l
find ./ -type d | wc -l
```

To flatten, I use this command:

```
find ./ -mindepth 2 -exec mv -i -v '{}' . \;
```

Problem is that when I get a count after running the flatten command, my count is off by 46.  After going through the list of files before and after (I have a backup), I found that the `mv` command is overwriting files *sometimes* even though I'm using `-i`.

Here's details from the log for one of these files being overwritten...

```
.//Vacation/CIMG1075.JPG -> ./CIMG1075.JPG
..more log
..more log
..more log
.//dog pics/CIMG1075.JPG -> ./CIMG1075.JPG
```

So I can see that it is overwriting.  I thought `-i` was supposed to stop this.  I also tried a `-n` and got the same number.  Note, I do have about 150 duplicate filenames.  Was going to manually rename after I flattened everything I could.

Is it a timing issue?
Is there a way to resolve?

NOTE:  it is prompting me that some of the files are overwrites.  On those prompts I just press `Enter` so as not to overwrite.  In the case above, there is no prompt.  It just overwrites.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?  There were some documented problems with non-atomicity of renames on earlier versions of OS X, up to and including 10.6 Snow Leopard, that *might* be a factor.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the reply.  I am on Yosemite, version 10.10.2.

Comment: IBest to write a script that finds the duplicate names, and renames them, maybe embedding the path name in the file, i.e. `Vacation_CIM...` and `dog pics_CIM...`. You'll have to be quote everything faithfully, because of spaces in your dir (and possibly file) names. Good luck.!

Comment: You could use `find . -type f | wc -l` to count the file names (that excludes directories).  Are any of the files links or symlinks?  I have a Mac and have not reproduced the behaviour you're seeing in a casual (84 file) experiment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the help.  That's what my problem was - symlinks.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the [manual entry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mv.1.html) clearly states:

> The -n and -v options are non-standard and their use in scripts is not recommended.

In other words, you should mimic the `-n` option yourself. To do that, just check if the file exists and act accordingly. In a shell script where the file is supplied as the first argument, this could be done as follows:

```
[ -f "${1##*/}" ]
```

The file, as first argument, contains directories which can be stripped using `##*/`. Now simply execute the `mv` using `||`, since we want to execute when the file doesn't exist.

```
[ -f "${1##*/}" ] || mv "$1" .
```

Using this, you can edit your `find` command as follows:

```
find ./ -mindepth 2 -exec bash -c '[ -f "${0##*/}" ] || mv "$0" .' '{}' \;
```

Note that we now use `$0` because of the `bash -c` usage. It's first argument, `$0`, can't be the script name because we have no script. This means the argument order is shifted with respect to a usual shell script.

Comment: This would have worked.  But it gave me the same result, which clue-ed me in that I must be doing something wrong.  Figured out I had 493 symlinks that were causing the difference.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not check if file exists, prior move? Then you can leave the file where it is or you can rename it or do something else...

Test -f or, [] should do the trick?

I am on tablet and can not easyly include the source.